# Installation problem on Raspberry Pi 4 Debian 10

Tags: cmake, dji-sdk

I can't install Onboard-SDK on my raspberry PI. What I should do?
I used instruction from and was blocked during use cmake ..:
https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/quickstart/development-environment.html

pi@raspberrypi:~/Onboard-SDK/build $ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster
```

pi@raspberrypi:~/Onboard-SDK/build $ gcc -v

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
```

pi@raspberrypi:~/Onboard-SDK/build $ cmake -version

```
cmake version 3.16.3
```

When I use cmake i've got an errors:
pi@raspberrypi:~/Onboard-SDK/build $ cmake ..

```
-- Found libusb-1.0:
-- - Includes: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
-- - Libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
Cannot Find FFMPEG
-- Found libusb-1.0:
-- - Includes: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
-- - Libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/api/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/platform/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/protocol/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/camera_stream/src/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/ori-osdk-core/protocol/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/ori-osdk-core/hal/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/advanced-sensing/ori-osdk-core/platform/linux/inc
Cannot Find FFMPEG
-----------OSDK_LIB_HEADERS_DIR------------
(/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/api/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/modules/inc/payload/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/modules/inc/flight/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/modules/inc/mop/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/platform/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/logger/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/utility/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/linker/armv7/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/modules/inc/filemgr)
-----------ADVANCED_SENSING_HEADERS_DIR------------
(/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/api/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/platform/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/protocol/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/camera_stream/src/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/ori-osdk-core/protocol/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/ori-osdk-core/hal/inc/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/sample/platform/linux/../../../osdk-core/advanced-sensing/ori-osdk-core/platform/linux/inc)
-- Found libusb-1.0:
-- - Includes: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
-- - Libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
Cannot Find FFMPEG

-- Enable OSDK Hotplug monitoring.
-- Found libudev:
-- - Includes: /usr/include
-- - Libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libudev.so

-- You can cmake with "-DCONFIG_TOOL=ON" to rebuild the config tool.

(........)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

pi@raspberrypi:~/Onboard-SDK/build $ cat /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log

```
The system is: Linux - 5.10.27-v7l+ - armv7l
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0

Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
0

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/3.16.3/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_df598/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_df598.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_df598.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_df598.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_df598.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_df598
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_df598.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_df598.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_df598
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_1ca99/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/usr/bin/cc -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c -quiet -dumpbase CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mtls-dialect=gnu -marm -march=armv6+fp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -version -o /tmp/cccCRwYx.s
GNU C17 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) version 8.3.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) version 8.3.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: bcc8c085e8c103b65550a3bb7c44a354
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp'
as -v -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -meabi=5 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o /tmp/cccCRwYx.s
GNU assembler version 2.31.1 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.31.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/lib/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp'
Linking C executable cmTC_1ca99
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc -v -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -o cmTC_1ca99
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/lib/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-rdynamic' '-o' 'cmTC_1ca99' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccOyodwJ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -X --hash-style=gnu -m armelf_linux_eabi -o cmTC_1ca99 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../.. -L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-rdynamic' '-o' 'cmTC_1ca99' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Parsed C implicit include dir info from above output: rv=done
found start of include info
found start of implicit include info
add: [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include]
add: [/usr/local/include]
add: [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed]
add: [/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
add: [/usr/include]
end of search list found
collapse include dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include]
collapse include dir [/usr/local/include] ==> [/usr/local/include]
collapse include dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed]
collapse include dir [/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> [/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
collapse include dir [/usr/include] ==> [/usr/include]
implicit include dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include;/usr/local/include;/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed;/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf;/usr/include]

Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
link line regex: [^( |.[/])(ld|CMAKE_LINK_STARTFILE-NOTFOUND|([^/]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/]*( |$)]
ignore line: [Change Dir: /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
ignore line: []
ignore line: [Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_1ca99/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/build]
ignore line: [make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc]
ignore line: [Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf]
ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c ada c++ go d fortran objc obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf]
ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
ignore line: [gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) ]
ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp']
ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c -quiet -dumpbase CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mtls-dialect=gnu -marm -march=armv6+fp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -version -o /tmp/cccCRwYx.s]
ignore line: [GNU C17 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) version 8.3.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)]
ignore line: [ compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0 GMP version 6.1.2 MPFR version 4.0.2 MPC version 1.1.0 isl version isl-0.20-GMP]
ignore line: []
ignore line: [GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072]
ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"]
ignore line: [ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"]
ignore line: [#include "..." search starts here:]
ignore line: [#include <...> search starts here:]
ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include]
ignore line: [ /usr/local/include]
ignore line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed]
ignore line: [ /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
ignore line: [ /usr/include]
ignore line: [End of search list.]
ignore line: [GNU C17 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) version 8.3.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)]
ignore line: [ compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0 GMP version 6.1.2 MPFR version 4.0.2 MPC version 1.1.0 isl version isl-0.20-GMP]
ignore line: []
ignore line: [GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072]
ignore line: [Compiler executable checksum: bcc8c085e8c103b65550a3bb7c44a354]
ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp']
ignore line: [ as -v -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -meabi=5 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o /tmp/cccCRwYx.s]
ignore line: [GNU assembler version 2.31.1 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.31.1]
ignore line: [COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/]
ignore line: [LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/lib/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/]
ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o' '-c' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp']
ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTC_1ca99]
ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc -v -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -o cmTC_1ca99 ]
ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc]
ignore line: [COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/lto-wrapper]
ignore line: [Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf]
ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c ada c++ go d fortran objc obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf]
ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
ignore line: [gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) ]
ignore line: [COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/]
ignore line: [LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/lib/:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/]
ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-rdynamic' '-o' 'cmTC_1ca99' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp']
link line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccOyodwJ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -X --hash-style=gnu -m armelf_linux_eabi -o cmTC_1ca99 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../.. -L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o]
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/collect2] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin] ==> ignore
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/liblto_plugin.so] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/lto-wrapper] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccOyodwJ.res] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc] ==> ignore
arg [-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s] ==> ignore
arg [--build-id] ==> ignore
arg [--eh-frame-hdr] ==> ignore
arg [-export-dynamic] ==> ignore
arg [-dynamic-linker] ==> ignore
arg [/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3] ==> ignore
arg [-X] ==> ignore
arg [--hash-style=gnu] ==> ignore
arg [-m] ==> ignore
arg [armelf_linux_eabi] ==> ignore
arg [-o] ==> ignore
arg [cmTC_1ca99] ==> ignore
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o] ==> ignore
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o] ==> ignore
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtbegin.o] ==> ignore
arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8]
arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf]
arg [-L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../..] ==> dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../..]
arg [-L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> dir [/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
arg [-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> dir [/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
arg [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ca99.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o] ==> ignore
arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
arg [--push-state] ==> ignore
arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
arg [--pop-state] ==> ignore
arg [-lc] ==> lib [c]
arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
arg [--push-state] ==> ignore
arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
arg [--pop-state] ==> ignore
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtend.o] ==> ignore
arg [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o] ==> ignore
collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8]
collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> [/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
collapse library dir [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../..] ==> [/usr/lib]
collapse library dir [/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> [/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
collapse library dir [/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf] ==> [/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
implicit libs: [gcc;gcc_s;c;gcc;gcc_s]
implicit dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf;/usr/lib;/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf]
implicit fwks: []

Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_cf360/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_cf360.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_cf360.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_cf360.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++ -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_cf360.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_cf360
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_cf360.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_cf360.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_cf360
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_f2b75/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2b75.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2b75.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Onboard-SDK/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2b75.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2b75.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2b75.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-marm' '-march=armv6+fp'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf -D_GNU_SOURCE /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -quiet -dumpbase CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mtls-dialect=gnu -marm -march=armv6+fp -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2b75.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -version -o /tmp/ccnaigJo.s
GNU C++14 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) version 8.3.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/include/c++/8
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/8
/usr/include/c++/8/backward
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) version 8.3.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.20-GMP
```

(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libswresample-dev libavformat-dev libavfilter-dev
```

Resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear

> Cannot Find FFMPEG

You can install it via `sudo apt install ffmpeg libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavfilter-dev`

Comment: **I did it earlier.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Onboard-SDK/build $ sudo apt install ffmpeg**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install libav-tools as https://wiki.debian.org/ffmpeg suggests.

Comment: sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavfilter-dev resolved the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I've edited the answer. You can now mark it as answer/resolved